# Favicon not loading

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, favicon

I need to change the default favicon in Symfony 2, I have executed `app/console assets:install web --symlink` and made public my images folder inside the web directory. Check the following picture.

[image: Web folder with favicon]

In the base I have this by default:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
```

I have tried to change that link to a lot of things containing the path to that public folder, but I have failed, the favicon does not load, besides I have read, that the favicon takes some time to show up (I don't know if this is completely accurate), but I don't know what is correct or what not. Can any one point me to the correct way?

Comment: it should be `asset('bundles/teamerptransport/images/favicon.ico')` however as a rule of thumb, it is advised to put your favicon at the root of your web folder.

Comment: Check the source code and see the path of image corresponds to favicon

Comment: @Abel has your problem with the favicon been solved?

Comment: Yes what I used was Boris Guéry´s solution from this comments. I had tested it, but it did not work immediately... Yours is also fine and is the first actually.

Comment: OK. I recommend placing the favicon directly in the `web` folder if possible, because some browsers (IE) expect the favicon to be in your website's root: `http://www.example.com/favicon.ico`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
```

refers to `web/favicon.ico`, but your actual favicon file is located in `web/bundles/teamerptransport/images`. That's probably the reason why it doesn't work.

Why did you put the favicon in a bundle? Does it only apply to a part of your application? If the favicon should be displayed throughout the whole application, I'd suggest to place it directly inside the `web` folder (replacing the default one that comes with Symfony's Standard Edition).

This has the added benefit that some browsers will look for a favicon at `http://www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico`, so putting the file there will make sure those browsers will find it.

If you have any problems with no or old favicons being displayed in a browser, even though you're sure the URL is correct, make sure to clear your browser cache.

By the way, be sure to visit [this favicon generator website](http://realfavicongenerator.net) (and read their FAQ) for some interesting tips on favicon files and browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should specify the good bundle !

```
{% image 
    @teamerptransport/Ressources/images/favicon.ico
%}
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{asset_url}}"/>
{%endimage%}
```

I think your image is in your bundle/ressources/public/images as recommanded